# Trying To Create WordPress Download page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to create a separate download page in WordPress when the visitor clicks on a download link, it will be redirected to a download page with a counter.

I don't know what is the missing part in the below code!

Any help appreciated :)

```html
<form action="https://www.example.com/download-page" method="post" target="_blank">
  <input name="downloadfile" value="https://www.mhotspot.com/mHotspot_setup_4.exe" type="hidden">
  <p></p>
  <div align="center">
    <input 
      class="aligncenter wp-image-1496" 
      alt="submit" 
      src="https://www.softloris.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/download-button.png" 
      type="image" 
      width="250" 
      height="auto">
  </div>
  <div align="center"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please explain what's happening when you click on the button that's different from what's expected.